# How do I make a system that can import XML from other systems laravel

Tags: xml, laravel, laravel-5

I know the question is a little broad, but I have an accounting system in the company that I work with and we have to make the data available to a transparency portal. In the accounting system is generated an XML file with all the information of releases and etc. ... how do I make a system that could import that XML with the information. Do you have a package in Laravel 5x that does it for me? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use this package `orchestra/parser`: https://github.com/orchestral/parser.

You load the XML somewhere your app can access it. Then follow the package instructions to parse XML.

This package `Nathanmac/Parser` parses from several formats including XML. Also have a look: https://github.com/nathanmac/Parser

Comment: Any tutorial on how to use the package?

Comment: @helioh3 Have you considered reading any of the documentation, or trying to write code?

Comment: Yes. Forgive my ignorance. I want to read the Documentation, I could not find it.

Comment: There is documentation in each of the packages I gave you. Follow the links.